# Game development using Unity for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, unity-game-engine

I have decided to use the game engine Unity to develop my game for iPhone. But I need to use some functions built into the iOS SDK.

If I choose to develop using Unity, can I still use functions from the standard iOS SDK? Like functions to access a url, etc...

Answer (score 3):

When you compile a Unity project for iOS it takes your C# or JavaScript code and AOT compiles it to a native dll.  It then creates an xcode project which loads that dll.  You can add native objectiveC, or C/C++ functions to this project and expose them for calling from the Unity engine.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html

Unity also has built-in methods for [accessing URLs](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Comment: Note: Plugins are a Pro-only feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the Unity SDK is built, but if it's a static Objective-C library then you can access iOS SDK functions without any problems. If its a script engine where you develop your scripts outside the IDE then you may not access iOS function.

Have you checked other engines/sdk's for your game development? I know that [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is **well documented** and I know for sure that you can call iOS methods.
Good  luck!

Comment: hi i am using cocos2d right now..but its got limitations so i will need to switch to a 3d engine

Answer (score 0):

I used both unity3d and corona which are very good at their field, and yes you can use all standart SDK over them, sometimes you need to do tricks though (which is quite a pain). If you are developing a 3d game and familiar with NVIDIA PhysX engine go for unity, it gives you nice features. But if you are clueless about collasions/rigidbodies/ragdolls etc you would have a hard time for sure.

As for 2d application development since I don't like Objective-C I prefer corona which you code in lua (easy to learn and use). You can use most of the IOS SDK in it without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I really reccomend you starting with Unity, it is the best engine I have ever used (I have used a ton of bad engines).

Unity is the best place to start and to stay. Coding, graphics and everything is simple to manage in this engine.

Unity is specially 3d but you can also build 2d games, some examples are Zombieville and OMG Pirates (very succesfull games on the appstore).